# Powershell script called from TaskScheduler that calls an exe

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a Powershell script that calls an exe, which works fine when manually executing the script.

However, when scheduling the script in Task Scheduler, everything is working except for the call to the exe. I also tried `Invoke-Command`, but that didn't help.

```
$servers="server1","server2"
$sbServer = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()

$cred = "password"
NET USE \\sourceserver\d$ /u:localserver\WDeployAdmin
$cred

foreach ($server in $servers)
{
    [void]$sbServer.AppendLine($server)
}

[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("D:\Temp\pushlist.txt", $sbServer.ToString())

&"D:\Temp\copyfileout.exe" "sourceserver" "d`$\Projects\eCommerce\Legacy\wwwroot" "d`$\webserv\wwwroot\website" "$true"

NET USE \\localserver\d$ /D /Y
```

The behavior I am seeing when the Powershell script is called from Task Scheduler is the copyfileout.exe is called but the parameters are not passed in. The pushlist.txt is used by copyfileout.exe as destinations that have files copied to them from the sourceserver.

If it helps, copyfileout.exe is a C# console application.  The TaskScheduler is running under an account that is local administrator, the task is set to "Run with highest privilleges".

Comment: You can follow these instructions https://blog.kaniski.eu/2017/04/scheduling-a-powershell-script-with-arguments/

Comment: Can you show your full script? Or at least enough to give us more context?

Comment: Script has been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being with the "Start In" option of the Action in the TaskScheduler.  For some reason, the exe is not picking that up, and using the system32 directory.  Changed the console app to handle this.  Thanks for the replies/feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I find it most reliable to use `Start-Process` when running external applications in powershell. Here is an example from one of my scripts.

```
$process = Start-Process -FilePath $gamPath -ArgumentList "update", "group", $emailGroup, "add", "member", "user", $emailAddress -Wait -PassThru -WindowStyle Hidden
if ($process.ExitCode -ne 0)
{
    Write-Output "Failed"
}
```

Remember also that you should specify the full path to the exe, as the task scheduled script may not run in the directory where it is located.

Comment: I've added the script that I am able to replicate the issue with.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that I tried using Start-Process with the same results, works manually but does NOT work through TaskScheduler